# Не перетираемые записи в memcached

Tags: php, memcached

Судя по [документации Memcached](http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.ispersistent.php) в PHP, объекты записываются в память и хранятся там до тех пор, пока:

- не наступит срок годности данных
- не перезагрузится сервер
- не закончится память, выделенная под memcached

Меня интересует последний пункт. Если в памяти memcached закончилось место, то для записи в неё новых данных будут удалены старые данные. А у меня есть определённые данные, которые должны строго находиться в памяти и не перетираться новыми данными. Какие есть варианты? В документации я не нашёл параметр, позволяющий выдавать ключам резистивность к перезаписи.

Comment: Memcached не гарантирует сохранности данных. Например, при сбое или перезагрузке все данные будут утеряны. Так что, полагаю, проблема нерешаемая.